# Set of units of rings of square matrices

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory

In my algebra class, a claim was made that the set of units of rings of square matrices with coefficients on a ring $\mathbb Z$ is the set of matrices for which its determinant is a unit in $\mathbb Z$. Does this hold for any ring $A$?

Intuitively, since $\det(BC) = \det(B)\det(C)$ and $\det(I) = 1$, given $B \in M_{n}(A)$, if there exists $B^{-1}$ such that $BB^{-1} = I$ then $\det(B)$ must be an unit in $A$, since $\det(B)\det(B^{-1}) = 1$.

However, I don't know where to start to prove that every matrix for which its determinant is a unit in $A$ is also a unit in $M_{n}(A)$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding a bit on the comment above about adjugates. One consequence of Cramer's rule (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule) is a formula for the inverse of a matrix $M$ of the form

$$M^{-1}=\frac{1}{\det(M)}Adj(M)$$

Don't worry too much about what the adjugate matrix is if you don't already know. It is just a matrix that assembles a bunch of different minor determinants of $M$ and makes sense for a matrix over any ring. Thus this formula makes sense whenever the determinant of $M$ is a unit in $A$. Hence any square matrix with entries in a $A$ has an inverse provided that its determinant is a unit in $A$.